# Should PHP exception try/catch blocks be specific to the exception?

Tags: php

I am trying to determine what is best practice for PHP exception handling.

For example, a basic function which checks validation:

```
public function myValidationChecker(MyForm $form, $dateFrom, $dateTo) {
    try {

        $start = $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d'); // could cause exception
        $finish = $dateTo->format('Y-m-d'); // could cause exception

        // lots more logic here

        $diff = $dateTo->diff($dateFrom); // could cause different exception

        // ... more non-exception causing logic

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        $this->log($e->getMessage());

        // attach error to $form so that code stops executing
        // & display generic error message to user
    }
}
```

Should I potentially be catching a specific exception rather than just `\Exception`, e.g. `UnexpectedValueException` or `InvalidArgumentException` and have the catch surrounding just that specific, scary area of code?

Or equally, is it best to surround the entire function, in the case that there is an exception that I have not planned for? Either way, in this catch block, the code is prevented from being executed, as after this function is run, `$form` is checked for an error message.

Comment: it depends on your overall error-handling strategy. If these exceptions are unwanted but anticipated as potentially likely in certain scenarios, then you could handle them specifically, then it doesn't override a more global strategy for dealing with completely unexpected errors - if you have such a thing. Having said that, using exceptions to handle format validation errors is potentially expensive and sometimes considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: P.S. how would `->format('Y-m-d')` cause an exception? Struggling to think of an example. Have you managed to produce such a thing?

Comment: @ADyson it's a pretty random example (pseudo-code). I guess if you tried to call `->format` on an array it would bork. Forgive me if that's not true though :)

Comment: @ADyson and thanks for the heads up about exceptions being expensive for validation, it wasn't something that I had considered.

Comment: Yes it would fall over if the variable you call it on isn't a DateTime...but surely you've ensured that already elsewhere? If you're validating user input (which I assume is the purpose of this) then that raw user input will likely be strings, numbers etc. To even consider calling the format() method you need to have parsed that string to a DateTime first. And if it wouldn't parse (e.g. because the string can't be reliably interpreted as a date) you're likely to get an error at that stage instead.

Comment: P.s. here's a simple way to validate date strings without using exceptions: https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/validate-date-input-string-in-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only ever catch the exception you know how to handle. Don't just catch, because you want it, catch them only when you need to. Most of the time the exception should bubble up and be caught by the general logger, preferably the one built-in to PHP.

If you know what to do with the exception, then you know what you need to catch. Catch the exception you need to handle and let the others bubble up.